# daylight saving (London) issue in php: CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone, dst

I am trying to convert any timezone to LONDON timezone. At this moment the daylight concept is not considered.

When my time is : **07-04-2016 03:00 PM** expected in LONDON is : **07-04-2016 10:30 AM**

In my case it is : 07-04-2016 09:30 AM

Here is my php code in CI Helper:

```
function convert_datetime_to_utc_timezone($date, $timezone) {

    if ($date != '') {
        $ci = & get_instance();
        $dformat .= "Y-m-d H:i:s";
        $zone = get_list_of_all_timezone();

        $user_time_zone = $zone[$timezone];

        $convert_date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($user_time_zone));
        $convert_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        return $convert_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

**Note:** $user_time_zone = 'Asia/Calcutta';

Comment: London should have GMT+1 zone

Comment: need to change code? suggest please!

Comment: Code base is permanent, so it should work when LONDON timezone is without daylight saving or vice versa!

Comment: Are you testig this in localhost?

Comment: No, its Live. Actually I am doing with easycron, their timezone is London.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert your local time to London time, then please use 'Europe/London'. The general time zones like UTC, EST etc wouldn't consider day light saving time.

```
$your_date = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ( $your_date ) );

$newyork_time = new DateTime ( $your_date, new DateTimeZone ( 'America/New_York' ) );

$london_time = new DateTime ( $your_date, new DateTimeZone ( 'Europe/London' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want London time, then set the timezone to 'Europe/London', not UTC.

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $format = 'd-m-Y H:i A';
php > $input_timezone = 'Asia/Calcutta';
php > $input_datetime = '07-04-2016 03:00 PM';
php > $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input_datetime, new DateTimeZone($input_timezone));
php > $datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
php > var_dump($datetime->format($format));
string(19) "07-04-2016 10:30 AM"
```